# Appending different word documents keeping the attributes of each document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have an application which generates different kinds of reports. Now the client wants to add an option where all the reports are generated simultaneously one after the other in a single document. I've been trying to do this, particularly inserting an file as an object but the footers and headers are lost.

I have seen many applications which claim to achieve my goal but I am not allowed to buy a license and they cannot be used programatically. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hard way, that's the only method I've found.

Basically, you have to:

1) Open the file to be inserted

2) use Doc.INSERTFILE to insert the file at the required spot in the main doc.
    Make note of the location of the insertion, the active section etc.

3) now loop through all the sections of the file being inserted, and copy
    over everything about those sections
    to the new sections in the main doc,
    including header footer info,
    formatting, page layout etc.

It's a pain, but as far as I can tell, there is no other easier way to get there.

Comment: I have some answers about your comment, first, what do you mean with Doc.INSERTFILE? I've been looking fro a method with that name in WordDocument and WordApplication unsuccessfully. Second, Is there anyway to go through all elements of a word document? like, for element in document do…?

Comment: Certainly an annoying solution, but it is slowly working. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry it took so long for me to comment back. About the InsertFile, it should be a method on the RANGE object. Sorry about that. I'll edit my answer.Second, as to some way to enum the elements. Unfortunately not that I know of. You just have to test the heck out of it, and when you discover that you've missed something you need, you add it. Glad to hear it's working for you though!